# In C#, how to pre-pend text string to a file without changing original encoding

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I would like to pre-pend(to the beginning) a file with a string in C#.
Currently, I am just replacing content of the file with my string plus original content.
**I DO NOT WANT TO DO THIS, because streamwriter will mess-up encoded characters.**

Is there a way to pre-pend a text file without changing it's original encoding(of each character).

There is gotta be a way.

Comment: Do you know the encoding of the file?

Comment: I don't. File can have any encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code at the bottom of [this page](http://www.personalmicrocosms.com/Pages/dotnettips.aspx?c=15&t=17) appears to let you Read a file in, retain the encoding and then write it back out using the same encoding.  You should be able to modify this to do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Just read the file without ever decoding the bytes. And you have to choose an encoding for your header - ASCII seems to be the safest choice in your situation.

```
const String fileName = "test.file";
const String header = "MyHeader";

var headerBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(header);
var fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);

using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
{
    stream.Write(headerBytes, 0, headerBytes.Length);
    stream.Write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
}
```

Note that the code directly operates on the stream and does not use a [`TextReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.aspx) or [`TextWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.aspx) (this are the abstract base classes of [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) and [`StreamWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx)). You can use a [`BinaryReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) and [`BinaryWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) to simplify accessing the stream if you have to deal with tasks complexer then just reading and writing array.

Comment: Note that if the original file has a header, this may not be what you want.  Given an original file formatted as `OLDHEADER+OLDDATA`, you may want to end up with `OLDHEADER+NEWDATA+OLDDATA` rather than `NEWHEADER+NEWDATA+OLDHEADER+OLDDATA` or `NEWDATA+OLDHEADER+OLDDATA`.

Comment: Doesn't the text added to the file need to be encoded in the same manner as the original file?  This won't do that.

Comment: I might need to replace oldheader with newheaer.

Comment: The opener didn't state that this is a requirement. If it is required to use the same encoding, he has to solve a very hard problem - he has to detect the encoding of the file. There is no simple solution in the general case and one has to use statistical methods and heuristics to detect the correct encoding with a high probability.

Comment: How can you extract the old header without knowing the encoding? Is it fixed size or terminated with a special code? Or is it a binary header?

Comment: header is contained within predefined start and end tags, that's how I find it

Comment: So you know the encoding of the header?

Comment: I was really looking for a way to do what I want to do without decoding/encoding anything, but now, I see that it is almost impossible. Can you take a look at my answer on the bottom and let me know if that is a workable solution?

Answer (score 1):

[Text encoding is a funny thing](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).  If you are writing code that is going to be interpreted as encoded **characters**, the compiler must be told (or it might assume) how the bytes ought to be arranged to represent particular characters.  If your program is agnostic of the encoding of the files with which you will be working, then how do you intend to indicate to the compiler how it should interpret the array of bytes in that file?

You could consider reading the characters as a stream of **bytes** instead of a stream of **characters** if you don't know how to instruct the compiler to interpret those bytes (i.e. you don't know what encoding will be used at run-time).  In that case, you have to hope that whatever basic characters you chose to append to the beginning of the file can be universally recognized in any encoding; this is because you will be appending **bytes** and not **characters** to the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I found this which let's me get correct encoding of the file:
http://www.personalmicrocosms.com/Pages/dotnettips.aspx?c=15&t=17

then I can use that encoding in the streamwriter.

Is it safe to use?

Comment: That's the page that I linked to in my answer.  If your files are unicode-y, it should work.

Comment: It will work for a very limited number of encoding - Unicode encodings with byte order mark. That are three encodings out of more then one hundred. You can have a look at http://www.mozilla.org/projects/intl/UniversalCharsetDetection.html but I doubt it is worth the afford to implement it (but it would be great because I am not aware of any .NET library providing this kind of functionality). The way to go is probably just requiring that the file is in Unicode - if not, the user (knowing the encoding) must convert it. Not the best possible usability but given the complex problem, acceptable.